# Weird subprocess issue with Django

Tags: django, apache2, subprocess, mod-wsgi, pdflatex

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question, but after searching through 3 pages for "django subprocess", I, for one, could not find the answer to my particular problem.

I'm trying to run `pdflatex` on `tex` file, but for some reason in Django it doesn't produce anything. It works just fine in a regular python script, though. I've omitted most of the code here, but this is basically the important bit. I'm running this on apache2 with mod_wsgi, and I suspect that it might be an apache permissions related problem, dunno though.
Thanks in advance.

```
import subprocess
test = subprocess.Popen(['pdflatex','/home/sheepz/test.tex'],shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
log = open('/home/sheepz/log.log', 'w')
log.write(str(test.communicate()))
log.close()

the content of the file "log.log":

('This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)\n restricted \\write18 enabled.\n**\n! End of file on the terminal... why?\n', None)
```

EDIT: 
The solution for this issue is quite easy. I just want to add it here, so everyone who's having trouble with this, can find it. Basically it involves running the site as a different user rather than www-data using the [WSGIDaemonProcess](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess) configuration directive. Here is a minimal configuration:

```
ServerName www.mysite.com
ServerAlias *mysite.com
WSGIDaemonProcess www.mysite.com user=joe group=joe home=/home/joe/
WSGIProcessGroup www.mysite.com
```

Also, it would be advisable to add `WSGIRestrictStdout Off` to your httpd.conf, because, as far as I understand, mod_wsgi ignores any process that tries to use stdout. Thanks, Graham.

Comment: What OS do you use? SE Linux enabled?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, so SELinux is not installed by default.

Comment: WSGIRestrictStdout is not needed it you use mod_wsgi 3.X as now defaults to allow stdout access as users preferred to write non portable WSGI applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the absolute path to 'pdflatex' in command. Apache user PATH may not look in same directories as your personal account does. Also, Apache runs as a special user that isn't going to have write access to where you can. Suggest you use mod_wsgi daemon mode and specify that that daemon process runs as you and not the Apache user. Read up documentation on mod_wsgi site as to how to do that.

Comment: thanks, I will read up on this, but will leave this question open until I have solved the issue.